# Specify to Kubernetes when a Pod is "busy"

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, load-balancing, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

One of my micro service is running on Kubernetes.
I would like to specify to K8s load balancer when a pod is busy because the behaviour that I get currently is not ok.

**One example:**

I have 8 pods running, each pod can process 1 request at a time. Each request take from 70 to 100% of the CPU core allocated to the pod.
But when I send 8 requests to my application, Kubernetes does not dispatch those requests to the 8 pods but try to use only one. And since I'm blocking (via threadpool) each replica of app to use only one thread at a time, of course requests are queued for pod 1.

**So my question is:** How can I tell Kubernetes that POD 1 is busy and that load-balancer must dispatch request 2 to POD 2 ?

**Note:** For dev and test purpose I'm using Docker Desktop (Docker for Windows) on Windows 10 and kubectl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As prometherion suggested you can use the liveness probe and also i would suggest to add the `rediness probe` together.

you can have a look at the official document : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

Sometimes, applications are temporarily unable to serve traffic. For example when, application first need to load large data or configuration files during startup.

In such cases, you don’t want to kill the application, but you don’t want to send traffic either there to pods. K8s provides readiness probes to detect and mitigate these situations. A pod with containers reporting that they are not ready does not receive traffic through Kubernetes Services.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried readiness config but Kubernetes behaviour is still the same. Pod is correctly disabled but Kubernetes does not dispatch request to others pods..

Comment: from service check labels are same with pod and service.

Comment: Yes it is same labels

Comment: if container running inside pod then status of pod will be ready and service will divert traffic. Unless and untill container is not running or application end point is not giving 200 service will transfer ttraffic to pods.

Comment: I consider that your answer is ok because it respond to my question. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem because the problem is actually in another place, I have realized it after asking this question.

Comment: @FrixG great thing matter is, get to know abt the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [LivenessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-command)

when a Pod will not able to handle a request its IP will be removed from Service endpoints, so no traffic will be forwarded to it.

LivenessProbe can be [TCP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-tcp-liveness-probe) or [HTTP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request)

Comment: @Harsh Manvar answer is more suitable: LivenessProbe & ReadinessProbe FTW

Comment: you provided the simplest solution I was thinking big big later reading your answer in my mind comes about LivenessProbe & ReadinessProbe comes;

Comment: @prometherion thanks for yout answer. Like you said answer from Harsh Manvar is more suitable, so I will accept this one.